# eth says that I just mined something: now what?

Tags: ethereum

I'm using eth to GPU mine for Ethereum. After running for 10 minutes, it said:

`i  23:58:32|gpuminer0  Mined #7a877124ΓÇª (parent: #d4e56740ΓÇª )`

If this were Bitcoin, I'd go check it out on blockchain.info and also rejoice that I just got 25 BTC. What did I accomplish for Ethereum and how do I confirm it?